# Jquery Mobile multiselect box not working properly inside phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have developed a phonegap android application using jquery mobile.  In that I have a form with a multi-select box.  The form works only if there are only limited number of entries available in the multi-select box.  If there are many items in the multi-select box then the form is not working.  See the screenshots below.

**The below 3 screens will explain the problem**

**Screen 1**
The parent form with the multi-select box 'Select Group'.  Also few data inputted in the form.

[image]

**Screen 2**
The multi-select box was touched and the content goes out of screen (there are 20+ groups). Selected 2 groups and clicked the x cross button to go back to the parent form

[image]

**Screen 3**
The value selected in the parent form disappears and also the selected values on the multi-select box also not pulled to the parent form.

[image]

If the multi-select box shows only a limited number of values which doesn't overflow the screen it works perfect.  Can anyone help me.

HTML code

```
<select name="bk_groupids" id="bk_groupids" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false"></select>
```

Using Jquery the values are appended as below

```
$('#bk_groupids').append('<option value="" data-placeholder="true">Select Group</option>');
$('#bk_groupids').append('<option value="1">Group 1</option>');
$('#bk_groupids').append('<option value="2">Group 2</option>');
etc...
```

Comment: When you select more than one option, the selectmenu isn't updated? Or when you append elements dynamically into selectmenu, they don't appear?

Comment: @Omar It doesn't matter whether I select a single value of multi values.. Whatever I select or even if I don't select, the parent form resets.

Comment: It looks like previous page - form - is removed from DOM when you open the selectmenu. Because a non-native multi-select selectmenu is converted into a dialog page, so you actually navigate to a new page. I don't if JQM behaves the same without cordova. I'll try to reproduce it.

Comment: @Dawson it's related to cordova. http://plnkr.co/edit/130gyA7RJUhUqZ7xaGAf?p=preview

Comment: I suggest you open a ticket https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/ btw, are you using a multi-page or single page model?

Comment: Cordova has nothing to do with the frontend presentation of an app. If you are having JS/HTML5/CSS issues, it's a compatibility issue with the native webview of the platform(s) you are developing for. Cordova has no affect on this. You would have the same issue if you tried building an android app with a webview and no cordova.

Comment: @omar I am using single page view. Meaning I have one index.html where all pages are exist.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on a different platform, e.g. iOS?

Comment: @omar - It behaves the same in Windows platform.  I created a simple html page with a single multi-select box.  I noticed that when I set `data-native-menu=true` then `pagebeforeshow` of the parent is calling where I reset the form.  But when the multi-select box is small then `pagebeforeshow` is not calling. If `data-native-menu=false` then things are working normal for any sizes... but placeholder is not possible.

Comment: post your issue on https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/ with explanation. It's also advisable to create an example reproducing the issue. Dont forget to mention cordova.